# Chrome crashes if I try to open it with Python/Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

When I run the code Chrome opens the URL but after about 2 seconds it crashes. It also says on the top of the chrome window "Chrome is being controlled by automated test software"

I am running the compatible version of the chrome driver for my version of chrome.

This is my code. How can I fix the crashing?

```
    #from config import keys
    from selenium import webdriver

    def order():
        driver = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver')
        driver.get('https://www.youtube.com/')


    if __name__ == '__main__':
        order()
```

Answer (score 0):

as you created the driver object in the scope of order()
after the execution of the order() is done all the local variables are removed.

You must have to declare driver as the global variable

```
from selenium import webdriver

# declare global varible driver 
driver = None
def order():
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver')
    driver.get('https://www.youtube.com/')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    order()
```

Otherwise, you can add time.sleep() to wait for a while

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver

def order():
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver')
    driver.get('https://www.youtube.com/')

    # will wait for 5 seconds
    time.sleep(5)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    order()
```